# Android Listview selection color with custom background

Tags: android, listview, background, selection

I've got a problem with android ListView and the selection color. So I've a ListView under a Spinner and for this ListView I've made an ArrayAdapter which is setting a backgroundcolor depending on the item. (This isn't seen at the screenshots)

Now when I click on one item there is no selection color visible. For this i made a selector like this:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:drawable="@color/SelectionColor" android:state_pressed="true" android:state_focused="true"/> </selector>
```

and added to the listview:

```
android:listSelector="@drawable/item_selector"
android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
```

I added drawSelectorOnTop because without that the selection color isn't visible.

The problem now is that at android 4 it looks like this: 
[click here](http://www.imagebam.com/image/f36de8257242195)

and at android 2.3.3 like this:
[click here](http://www.imagebam.com/image/6554c1257242197)

So how can i set the selection color that it looks the same for both versions. And preferably so that the text is still visible.

**EDIT:**
Thanks to Basim. That solves the problem that it looks different depending on the android version. But the text is still not visible if i have the drawSelectorOnTop entry in the listview or the selection isn't visible if i haven't this entry.

Comment: Post your complete listview layout, and if appropriate the list item layout.

Comment: If still relevant, just use color with some transparency. Instead of using #fefeff use #4Cfefeff

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this selector,

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<!-- Selector style for listrow -->
<item 
 android:state_selected="false"
    android:state_pressed="false" 
    android:drawable="@drawable/normal_shape" />
<item android:state_pressed="true" 
    android:drawable="@drawable/gradient_bg_hover" />
<item android:state_selected="true"
 android:state_pressed="false" 
    android:drawable="@drawable/gradient_bg_hover" />
</selector>
```

normal_shape.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle" >

    <gradient
        android:angle="270"
        android:endColor="#fefeff"
        android:startColor="#d5dbe7" />

    <stroke
        android:width="1dp"
        android:color="#acd9dd" />

</shape>
```

gradient_bg_hover.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
  <!-- Gradient BgColor for listrow Selected -->
  <gradient
      android:startColor="#d9dd00"
      android:endColor="#e6ea02"
      android:angle="270" />


</shape>
```